# Closest distance twice in a multimap

Tags: java, arrays, logic

Hello I have the to find nearest points to another one.
I've started by checking if the distance if one point (that i call x ) and another is close. 
Then I store it in multimap(Int,int) tab with as key the point called x and ad values the closest points of point called x.
The problem is that I have same data twice, because If x is close to y, y is close to x too.
I have a list like this one :
`[[25:{26,27}],[26:{25,27}], [27:{25}]]` 
I've tried to compare the values with the keys and tried to remove them if a key is equal to a value to another key.
Could anyone help me to find the logic please ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suggest posting your code rather than describing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to make a two dimensional array to check if a pair is already visited or not. For example,

```
int[][] visited = new int[x][y];//a pair (x , y)
 for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
         if(!visited[x][y] && !visited[y][x]){
            //check if (x, y) or (y, x) is already visited
            //if the pair is not visited yet, do what you want for the pair.
            visited[x][y] = true;
            visited[y][x] = true;
         }
 }
```

Comment: in that case it's not better to check that:
-if i want to add a value it doesn't exist as a key anywhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to deal with it, is to exclude duplicate pairs from comprehension,
For example if you have a nested loop iteration, you can just iterate like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < points.size(); ++j) {
        ... you can safely evaluate distance here and put it in multimap
    }
}
```

general approach would be to establish some sort of predicate and compare two points only if its true for the, for example, in the code I provided earlier, predicate is that we compare point `points[i]` to `points[j]` only when `i < j`, meaning that you would compare two points only once.

Answer (score 0):

So i've tried something like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Multimap<Integer, Integer>>  detectNode(ArrayList<Point> arrayList) {
    ArrayList<Multimap<Integer,Integer>> allresults= new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    Multimap<Integer,Integer> key = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
    Double d=distance(arrayList.get(i),arrayList.get(j));
    if(d<5.0 && d!=0 && j>i) {
    key.put(i,j);
                              }         
                                                }
    if(!key.isEmpty()) {
    allresults.add(key);
                        }   
                                                 }
    return allresults;
                                                                      }
```

and i get this on the main:

[{25=[28, 29, 33]}, {27=[34, 35]}, {28=[29]}, {31=[32, 33]}, {32=[33]}]

which is almost ok.
The  thing that is missing now is to find that if number 33 belongs to key 25 so 31 and 32 belongs too to 25 !

I've tried this code below by checking if a value isn't a key somewhere else and same result:

[{25=[28, 29, 33]}, {27=[34, 35]}, {28=[29]}, {31=[32, 33]}, {32=[33]}]

```
public static ArrayList<Multimap<Integer, Integer>>  detectNode(ArrayList<Point> arrayList) {
    ArrayList<Multimap<Integer,Integer>> allresults= new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
         Multimap<Integer,Integer> key = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
            Double d=distance(arrayList.get(i),arrayList.get(j));
            if(d<5.0 && d!=0 && j>i) {
                if(allresults.isEmpty()) {
                key.put(i,j);
                                    }
                for (int k = 0; k < allresults.size(); k++) {
                    if(!allresults.get(k).containsKey(j) &&  !allresults.get(k).containsEntry(i,j)) {
                        key.put(i,j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                                    }
        }
        if(!key.isEmpty()) {
            allresults.add(key);
            }   
    }
    return allresults;
}
```